# Removing a hyperplane from flag manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

It should be known that if we remove a compact complex codimension one submanifold $X$ (hyperplane) of a flag manifold $Z=G/P$, then $Z\setminus X$ is a Stein manifold. 
I was wondering if anyone can give a reference to the proof?  Here $G$ is a complex Lie group and $P$ is a parabolic subgroup.

Comment: That's not true.  Let $Z$ be $\mathbb{C}P^1\times \mathbb{C}P^1$ and let $X$ be $\{p\}\times \mathbb{C}P^1$.

Comment: you probably are thinking of the case where the divisor is ample to make this go. If Pic(G/P)=Z you're good.

Comment: @DanielPomerleano: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give me a reference? Thanks –

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to look up "Bruhat decomposition".  In particular, if $X$ is the union of all (Zariski closures of) codimension one Bruhat cells, then $Z\setminus X$ is an affine space, thus Stein.  When the Picard group of $Z$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, there is a unique codimension $1$ Bruhat cell.  Thus $X$ is an irreducible Cartier divisor in $Z$, and $[X]$ is a generator of the Picard group of $Z$.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Which hyperplanes are Bruhat cell in a flag manifold? Thanks.

Comment: @user: Please look up "Bruhat decomposition".